# Нахождение упоминания в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строка `str`, в которой может находиться упоминание пользователя (например, `@username`).
Мне нужно узнать есть ли упоминание и, в случае его наличия, обрамить его `<span>`.

Comment: С чем у вас возникла проблема при решении данной задачи, и в чём, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: @Regent проблема в том, что уровень знаний в js/jquery у меня практически равен 0 (специализируюсь в back-end'e), но появилось срочная надобность реализовать эту задачу именно на js/jquery

Comment: ограничения на формат `username` есть? скажем пробелы, символы?

Comment: @cyadvert упоминание будет состоять из одного слова, в котором будут только цифры и буквы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант:

```js
var str = 'this is text with @thisUsername in it, and @theOther username';
$('#stringBefore').html(str);
str = str.replace(/(@\w+)/gm, "<span>$1</span>");
$('#stringAfter').html(str);
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Before:
<div id="stringBefore"></div>
After:
<div id="stringAfter"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!